# how to set default value of date column to a date that is 60 days from the current date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a column named Expiry of date and time type.

I want to set the default date to 60 days from my current date. That is expiry should reflect the date of after two months from the current date.

I tried this under calculated value:

= Today + 60

Plz help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the parantheses. Tested on a local SharePoint:

```
= [Today] + 60
```

as a calculated value worked perfectly for me.